# Mayhem: onMouseOver onMouseOut with div

Tags: javascript, html, onmouseover, onmouseout

Imagine moving your mouse left to right across this webpage fragment:

[image]

The gray box is a DIV. I want a **single** onMouseOver when mousing into it, and a **single** onMouseOut when exiting it.

What I actually get (left to right):

```
onMouseOver DIV
onMouseOut DIV
onMouseOver Flag
onMouseOut Flag
onMouseOver DIV
onMouseOut DIV
onMouseOver USA
onMouseOut USA
onMouseOver DIV
onMouseOut DIV
onMouseOver 2
onMouseOut 2
onMouseOver DIV
onMouseOut DIV
```

Whew!

How can I just get a single onMouseOver and onMouseOut for the container DIV?

Comment: I am not exactly sure so I won't post an answer *but* I think this is to do with event bubbling. How are you setting the event listener?

Comment: [Quirksmode has a wonderful article on this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html)

Comment: Are you sure you want to tag CSS and not JavaScript?

Comment: @zzzzBov 5 minutes with that article and I have it working! Please add your comment as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Quirksmode has a wonderful article on this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html).

Although if you feel like using jQuery you can use [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) events.